# GDB процесс дебага

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, gdb

В Microsoft Visual Studio есть встроенный дебаггер, который позволяет дизассемблировать выполняемый файл и ходить по строчкам ассемблера пошагово.

Вот так это выглядит визуально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли нечто подобное для GDB? Могу ли я как то ходить по строкам ассемблера и видеть состояние регистров и памяти?

Comment: В gdb это есть `(gdb) layout asm`, `disassemble`, а вот допилили ли поддержку в VS - это вопрос.

Comment: @VTT Скорее всего наоборот, спрашивается можно ли картинку с кодом и регистрами увидеть в gdb подобно как в VS

Comment: Ну не обязательно именно картинку. Интерес в пошаговой отладке ассемблера с возможностью иногда заглянуть в память и регистры.

Comment: А тут имеется ввиду отладка с использованием gdb из под VS или просто отладка с использованием gdb без VS? если второе, то команды из моего первого комментария

Comment: Попробую прогуглить эти команды

Comment: Вообще, я даже немного протупил. Мне не обязателен даже конкретный отладчик. Мне подойдет любой отладчик, который позволяет пошаго пройтись по ассемблеру некоего исходника. Про gdb я написал лишь потому, что компилил исходники с помощью gcc.

Comment: Как [ходить](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html) в gdb (вообще-то, стоит почитать всю [доку](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html#Top))

Comment: gdb может все если нужен интерфейс есть --tui

Answer (score 1):

Да, в gdb всё это можно сделать.

- Для перемещения на одну инструкцию есть команды [`stepi`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html#index-si-_0028stepi_0029) (или `si`) `nexti` (`ni`) с заходов в подпрограмму и без соответственно.
- Чтобы увидеть дизассемблированнй листинг текущей функции (или чего-то ещё) есть команда [`disassemble`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Machine-Code.html#index-listing-machine-instructions) (`disas`).
- Регистры можно распечатать командой [`info registers`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Registers.html#index-info-registers) (`i r`).
- Память по заданному адресу — командой [`x`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html#index-examining-memory) (мнемоника от *eXamine*). Например `x/16xb $rsi` распечатает 16 байт в 16-ричном виде, расположенных по адресу, указанному в регистре `rsi`.